# OpenGL GLSL bad accuracy in interpolation of distance in basic lightning (2D)

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, interpolation

i just made working (and it seems it works pretty fast) Ray Casting system to make basic lighting (something working like demoes here: http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/). It works like i wanted, but when i set for each vertex of lit-up area distance from player/light source, it's very badly interpolated and in example if i want to trim light/shadow to X in distance, i'm not getting circle but something that looks between circle and polygon/square. Picture should explain.

Also - i use it for my 3D project (game) with top-down camera, if that matters. (see pic below). Algorithm works great without working on shadders itself but drawing plain space on it. (without clipping etc.)

Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace; //vertex's position
layout(location = 1) in vec3 Normal; //normal, currently not used, but added for future
layout(location = 2) in vec2 vertexUV; //texture coords, used and works ok

out vec2 UV; //here i send tex coords
out float intensity; //and this is distance from light source to current vertex (its meant to be interpolated to FS)

uniform mat4 MVP; //mvp matrix
uniform vec2 light_pos; //light-source's position in 2d

void main(){
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);
    UV = vertexUV;
    intensity = distance(light_pos, vertexPosition_modelspace.xz); //distance between two vectors
}
```

And here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 UV; //tex coords
in float intensity; //distance from light source
out vec4 color; //output
uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler; //texture
uniform float Opacity; //opacity of layer, used and works as expected (though to be change in near future)

void main() {
    color = texture( myTextureSampler, UV );
    color.rgba = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    if(intensity > 5)
        color.a = 0;
    else
        color.a = 0.5;
}
```

This code should give me nice FOV clipped by circle, but instead i get something like that:
[image: It's clearly not a circle-like shape]

I'm not sure why it work as it work...

Comment: Also, dont mind textures and models, it's only for the time i work on other, more important stuff. I'll fill that in when i'm done with more pressing matters, and i hope some friend will help me with that as i suck with this kind of things ;)

Comment: What are we seeing in the picture? Is the grey alpha overlay a new polygon or is it the same vertices of the background, just made darker by the shader? If its a new polygon (which I think it is), maybe your threshold of 5 is just too big.

Comment: If i turn of that clipping by distance thing in fragment shader, i get standard [THIS](http://i.imgur.com/fOSixFg.png). I simply use ray casting to get points in 2D space (from 3D space, i dont care about OY here) from which i can create polygon (or using triangles fan) which is darker in picture from this comment. If i use special shader just for this darker polygon, and supply it with position of light source/player, i want to that darker effect slowly fade away (thus i compute direction). Unfortunatly it looks like it doesnt interpolate too good, as seen in picture from main post.

Comment: I understand now. But you are not interpolating at all. You are interpolating the intensity correctly, but you aren't interpolating the alpha at all: your if statement says your alpha is either 0 or 0.5, never anywhere in between. If you would want it to fade, you'd need color.a to be a function of intensity, something like color.a = 1 - intensity/100 (this would be a bad function, but just an example).

Comment: [This is how it's supposed to look, more circle-like](http://i.imgur.com/PLf61Zl.png)
[And this is idea of the way it should interpolate distance between vertices and decide how much visible shadow/light overlay is visible](http://i.imgur.com/MREclez.png)

Comment: I'm aware of it. I'd make it depending on intensity already, but as i stated in main post - i get wrong interpolation (and thats whole deal in this topic). See how it's not round and end in pixels that are exactly X away from center (player), but are somehow "cut" becouse of bad interpolation.

Comment: You will be able to make it look almost like a circle if you fade slowly, but it won't ever be a circle unless you use a texture mapped ontop of the polygons, which I think is your best bet right now. Simply make an alpha texture with a circle fading from dark to light and give the polygons coordinates to line up the circle.

Comment: I hoped there is some fix for it or maybe change of state in OpenGL. :/ Ok, thanks for answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

That is not an accuracy problem, that is algorithmical, it is easy to see if you take a triangle with all sides equal and put object on the one of the vertices. In other two vertices you would get same distance, and along the edge between those two distant points you will get the same distance, which is wrong as it should be bigger in the center of that edge.

This can be smoothed if you will use triangles with smaller angle at the light source.

**Update:** you still can get round shadows if you pass light position with each triangle and will use interpolated coordinates to calculate real distance in fragment shader.